# MySQL Query - SELECT based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I cannot find an answer to this seemingly easy problem. I need to execute a different SELECT statement based on a condition.

A simple example :

```
if <condition>

SELECT id FROM table;

otherwise

SELECT id FROM table WHERE variable=1;
```

In other words I need to add an additional WHERE clause depending on the condition, however the problem boils down to choosing a different SELECT clause based on whether the condition is true or false.

Comment: What means `condition`?

Comment: In my case its a **EXISTS ( subquery )** clause.

Comment: could you please put the example of condition? It would be better then ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE variable=1 OR <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

case statements can be used as well...

```
SELECT id FROM table
where case when variable is not null then variable else 1 end
=
case when variable is not null then @variable else 1 end
```

You'll probably want different logic in the case statements, but this is saying when variable has a value (not null) then use the where clause variable = @variable, else 1=1 (which brings back all rows / no filter).